# Problems appending correctly a row on a csv file

Tags: flutter, csv

Based on previous answers, I wrote this code:

```
Future<void> _addToCSV(List<dynamic> rowData, String fileName) async {
    final file = File('assets/$fileName');
    final csvRow = rowData.map((data) => '$data').join(',');
    await file.writeAsString('$csvRow\n', mode: FileMode.append);
  }
```

where rowData is a list of 5 elements, each element corresponding to a column of the row. I simply want to append the row on the csv file making sure that when I import it as data on Excel the columns are correctly splitted. The fact is that using comma as separator creates some problems on the new appended lines, as Excel isn't able to split correctly and sees commas inside the row text as separators.

What's the problem? Cause the old rows (appended in python using pandas) don't have these problems although having commas inside the text too, and Excel is able to split the columns perfectly.
I'm trying to figure it out based on the difference between old and new rows.

In particular, old rows are in this format:
DocumentTitle,"DocumentSummary","Text",Paragraph N.txt,"Question","Answer"

I'm pretty sure it's related to the fact that when there is a comma inside the text of a column, the text is wrapped inside " ", but I'm not sure, and I don't know if pandas library did this check automatically, cause when I first created the csv I didn't do any check of this type.
How can I solve maintaining comma as a separator? Is the problem related to the behaviour I noticed?
If any extra code or information is required, feel free to ask.